# what things and concept i should learn before learning magento 2

Tags: magento2, theme, plugin

I am a php , html , css , javascript developer and i have worked on wordpress , laravel also , now i am learning magento 2 and i am not understanding most of the things . i want to know what concepts should i learn before learning magento 2 so that i can understand the core of magento 2 coding
I have searched about this and found something like

> learn psr-4 coding standards
>
> Design patterns

and i am learning them but still i am in great difficulty in understanding things .

Comment: read Magento php developer guide https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/bk-extension-dev-guide.html

Comment: yes @AmitBera i am also reading magento developer guide but guide is like bouncer to me :) but i will try to read it more thoroughly . thanks

Comment: You can not easily understand Magento 2 at a few days. As you have worked on laravel on you may know about MVC and OOPS concept. Magento almost like MVC  and you must have good knowledge of OOPS. Suggest first you have to build  some small modules for understanding magento begin.Only work with Magento for long time, make u Magento 2 expert,

Comment: hmm oops concept might be same but use of command line , cache , file generations in generated folder things are little bit difficult ...

Comment: First, do not go to very deep like cache concept.